# jpa fetching data from cache not database eclipaslink

Tags: caching, jpa, eclipselink

Hi I am working in a small project where I am using jpa (eclipselink), I am running two same application with from different tomcat, they are using same schema, but if i am 
changing value form one application, the other application not fetching data from database,
it always return its local data, I have also tried this @Cacheable(false) in entity class and

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

in xml file but they are not returning latest data from database, my code is as follows:

```
EntityManager entityManager = GlobalBean.store.globalEntityManager();
String queryString = "select g from GlobalUrnConf g";
TypedQuery<GlobalUrnConf> globalUrnConfQuery = entityManager.createQuery
    (queryString, GlobalUrnConf.class);
return globalUrnConfQuery.getSingleResult();
```

I am fetching entity manager and factory in following ways -

```
  public EntityManagerFactory factory() {
    if (this.entityManagerFactory == null) {
     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FileUpload");
      }
      return this.entityManagerFactory;
  }
  public EntityManager globalEntityManager() {
    if (this.entityManager == null) {
      this.entityManager = factory().createEntityManager();
    }
    return this.entityManager;
 }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating EntityManagers, and are you closing/clearing them?  EntityManagers are required to have their own cache, so that ever entity read through it is managed and changes can be tracked.  So if you are keeping a hold of an EntityManager singleton without clearing it, everything will end up cached.

Comment: Hi Chris I have updated my above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are caching the EntityManager which is required to cache and hold onto managed entities tht are read through it for both identity purposes and to manage changes.  You can get around this by using a refresh query hint, or other query hints so they can avoid the caches, but it is probably better is you just manage the EntityManager's life and cache more directly and only obtain them as needed, or clear them at logical points when returned entities can be released.  Try calling EntityManager clear for instance.

Comment: Thanks dude its working on entitymanager.clear :) many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
return globalUrnConfQuery
    .setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.CheckCacheOnly)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Hi Sabuj, I have tried as per your suggestion but it is giving following exception - javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
 org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.throwNoResultException(EJBQueryImpl.java:1246)
 org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:750)
 com.ers.uday.fileupload.GlobalBean.getGlobalConfFromDb(GlobalBean.java:176)

Comment: it is only checking for records at cache, and there were no data in cache for this particular query. Alternately, you can use other cache option that will check first at cache, then it will check database.